# Traducir info de preguntas protegidas

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, traducciones

Pregunta de ejemplo:

[¿MySQL para empezar con SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13051/2027)

Texto actual

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

Texto sugerido:

> Esta pregunta está protegida para evitar respuestas tipo "gracias!", "¡Yo
>   también!", o spam de los nuevos usuarios. Para responder a
>   ello, usted debe haber ganado al menos 10 reputación en este sitio (el
>   bono asociación no cuenta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por alguna razón este texto está traducido dos veces en Transifex y una de las traducciones no estaba marcada como revisada, lo acabo de hacer y tras la próxima compilación ya debería verse.

Comment: Muchas gracias @konamiman

Answer (score 4):

¡Corregido! Solamente falta que se actualize la base de datos.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Que raro, aun me aparece el texto en ingles

Comment: Me puedes mandar una captura o imagen por fa?

Comment: @JuanM [Captura](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HfzTn.png) -- [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/127)

Comment: @Mariano creo que eso aparece en las preguntas que *ya* estaban cerradas por eso motivo (me imagino que el texto se almacena en otra parte). Estoy esperando en la cola de revisión para comprobar si el texto del motivo de cierre se ha actualizado pero me imagino que sí.

Comment: @MiquelColl Puede ser, no lo había pensado. Pero acá hay una protegida el 26/8 [Solicitudes ajax en Laravel](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/101/127) que sigue apareciendo en inglés ... Y acá el [listado de protegidas](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/321835/protected-questions-by-user)

Comment: Aqui esta la [imagen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fpthj.png)